# Error on different workspace: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, circular-dependency, stringify

```
/code/server/Chat.js:34
                    let stringToWrite = JSON.stringify(game, null, 2);
                                             ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at /code/server/Chat.js:34:46
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This functionality works fine in workspace A and production server. But I'm getting this error in workspace B. Both workspaces are macbooks and server is linux. I don't know how this could be circular structure in one computer while not on the other one, any ideas?

The functionality of this method is to turn Game State into a log that can be saved as a 2000 line .log file. Purpose is for production future debugging.

Here is how the log looks like. I removed all elements related to the game, because I'm pretty sure there is no circular structure there.
https://pastebin.com/dF8PsZKS

Tested:

- I researched what circular structure is, I haven't done anything like this
- I looked inside GameController, couldn't find a circular structure
- I looked at subclasses inside GameController, couldn't find a circular structure
- This works in the server & my machine
- Tried console.log(util.inspect(myObject))

Comment: It looks like you're storing a socket object, is that right? Pretty sure that's where the problem would be.

Comment: Yes I am storing a socket object: `socket: any`. What should I do about this? Wouldn't that object be helpful in debugging? Also how does this explain why sockets make the code crash in 1 workspace but not the other 2?